# How to include the values from two tables in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select
    t1.x,
    t2.y

from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
        on t1.x = t2.x
```

which is producing the following results:

```
x   y1
x   y2
x   y3
```

I, however, want it to produce the following, where the value from t1.x is also in the second column:

```
x   x
x   y1
x   y2
x   y3
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm trying to achieve this in PostgreSQL but I would also be interested in any solution in MySQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whoops. Fixed it.

Comment: The best way to do it depends on undisclosed details. Like referential integrity: is there a row for every `table2.x` in `table1`? Can there be more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.x, t1.x as y
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.x, t2.y
from table2 t2;
```

The `join` is only needed if you want to filter (or multiply) the rows, based on `x` being in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is what you need. But I suspect you just need `LEFT JOIN` with some tweak:

```
SELECT
    t1.x,
    COALESCE(t2.y, t1.x)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.x = t2.x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION:

```
select
    x,
    x as y
from table1
union
select
    t1.x,
    t2.y
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
on t1.x = t2.x
order by x
```

or

```
select
    t1.x,
    t1.x
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
on t1.x = t2.x
union
select
    t1.x,
    t2.y
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
on t1.x = t2.x
order by x
```